# Javascript: Function equivalent of `for (let p in this)`

Tags: typescript

Just since I'm curious, what is the function used by `for (let p in this)`? I'm refactoring code and would like to replace

```
const result: string[] = [];
for (let p in this) { result.push(p); }
```

with a call like `const result = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);`. But since I know this function does not return inherited properties (like the look does) I need to find a different solution. I'm quite sure there is one.

In my scenario a base model (a class every model extends) is `this`. And I want to get an array of all the fields (and properties [get/set]) the concrete type implements.

Edit: I've just added [an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUzCAtsgTgQwEYA2yAFAJSIDeAUIrYlslCFkqJLAosVDlgOaMAXIhxgAngBpEAByxxp2KGIDSyMcIDOULDDB8pAE2QaIO6VDhZhABTkKsSgCLHTMc5fLU63xDGBcjEzMLLE8aHwjA13csADpUDGx8IkQAXkRtEGQAbnCIgF88xHzcwqoIAhwNDUQAISrkAFk4IwJKIoEoRHQW5AJbeUUYYzJNbV0%20AG0AXXaI2ggELXpjEAIoMZ09GbTEGdz5xGBLLiIu6V8kKAALGA1PFY01qFjpEA1r4mlSbOKi7wYTBYj2eBzohTKFSqNUaYmarRQAA8oKgDDV6homr02l46LJBg4xABBXYAciJpNyRQAAglMLhCCRSB1GDI7IoxLVRogtFs%20JQVkCrrcNLEAPr4%20xKWq-QreTHndmErkANxwBCymwmDxud3Fko5tV2ao1OT%203lkMDVKMQEqV0rJtUpVEhSzgRFiBDgfGIYGQAHdELD4X0yLEeq0BlLhvdskA)

Comment: 1) That appears to be Typescript, not Javascript 2) the answer to your question depends on what `this` is.

Comment: There's no equivalent function in JS, `for ..in` is the only way to iterate through the prototype chain.

Comment: Added the tag to `typescript` and descibed `this`. Thank you for mentioning! So there actually is no other way? `for ... in` is the way to go to get the prototype chains properties?

Comment: There is definitely a different way to do it, but it's a lot more involved than just a simple `for..in` loop.  Do me a favor and provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating the situation when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE (so you should include the relevant class definition).  Once you do that I can write up a version which doesn't use `for..in` that behaves similarly.  Let me know once you've done this by mentioning @jcalz in a comment.

Comment: @jcalz Here you go: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUzCAtsgTgQwEYA2yAFAJSIDeAUIrYlslCFkqJLAosVDlgOaMAXIhxgAngBpEAByxxp2KGIDSyMcIDOULDDB8pAE2QaIO6VDhZhABTkKsSgCLHTMc5fLU63xDGBcjEzMLLE8aHwjA13csADpUDGx8IkQAXkRtEGQAbnCIgF88xHzcwqoIAhwNDUQAISrkAFk4IwJKIoEoRHQW5AJbeUUYYzJNbV0+AG0AXXaI2ggELXpjEAIoMZ09GbTEGdz5xGBLLiIu6V8kKAALGA1PFY01qFjpEA1r4mlSbOKi7wYTBYj2eBzohTKFSqNUaYmarRQAA8oKgDDV6homr02l46LJBg4xABBXYAciJpNyRQAAglMLhCCRSB1GDI7IoxLVRogtFs+JQVkCrrcNLEAPr4+xKWq-QreTHndmErkANxwBCymwmDxud3Fko5tV2ao1OT+3lkMDVKMQEqV0rJtUpVEhSzgRFiBDgfGIYGQAHdELD4X0yLEeq0BlLhvdskA

Comment: Thanks.  Please also put the code as plain text in the question itself, so that it's a [mre] without requiring anyone to navigate away from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to re-implement this:

```
function inheritedEnumerableKeys(x: object): string[] {
    const ret: string[] = [];
    for (let k in x) ret.push(k);
    return ret;
}
```

without using a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). This is possible, but it's not a one-liner.  Of [the different ways of traversing object properties in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties#traversing_object_properties), only `for...in` gives you inherited property keys; everything else only gives own properties.  So if you want to get inherited properties, you'll need to explicitly [walk the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and collect own properties from each one:

```
function inheritedEnumerableKeys(x: object): string[] {
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(x);
    const ownKeys = Object.keys(x);
    return (proto && typeof proto === "object") ?
        [...ownKeys, ...inheritedEnumerableKeys(proto)] :
        ownKeys;
}
```

It's a recursive function, but one could also write it as a loop, so that it's easier to compare to the `for...in` version:

```
function inheritedEnumerableKeys(x: object): string[] {
    const ret: string[] = [];
    for (let v = x; v && typeof v === "object"; v = Object.getPrototypeOf(v)) {
        ret.push(...Object.keys(v));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

---

Let's test it.  With your original `modelProperties()` definition, we get this output:

```
console.log(new MyModel().modelProperties); 
// ["propertyA", "_propertyB", "propertyB"]
```

If I change the implementation to:

```
get modelProperties(): string[] {
    return inheritedEnumerableKeys(this);
}
```

we get the same output:

```
console.log(new MyModel().modelProperties); 
// ["propertyA", "_propertyB", "propertyB"]
```

no matter which of the three versions of `inheritedEnumerableKeys()` we use.

And let's just test those three versions against something with an explicit prototype hierarchy:

```
const z = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const y = Object.assign(Object.create(z), { d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 });
const x = Object.assign(Object.create(y), { g: 7, h: 8, i: 9 });
```

All three versions of `inheritedEnumerableKeys()` produce

```
console.log(inheritedEnumerableKeys(x)); 
// ["g", "h", "i", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c"]
```

---

So, that's the answer to your question, as asked.

But in the absence of some strong use case to the contrary, I would recommend using the `for...in` loop directly, which is simpler, more idiomatic, and quite possibly more performant than either of the other approaches.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#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-XxinvOX7EAAbjgBBZLmeieE+jZvh+54hnUYEQTkv7xrIMBgVsiDvmeC5IekK4hhuRT+h2lRwEQsQEHAfDEGAyAAO49n2U5kLEyYxumn5Zk2P4APQCYgcoAEQIQui6iVIol4UBF7SYg4n4V+olKkUapUcgNF0cQLJshWPJJPytYiqQDyIEJImiXwimiTCdkwHZBh2cgdnAHZOB2XgdkQGpiCYlQZTYri+KEogADq4HmrKAAqrLphYSgKAAwjCOC6AASlMzDzCByDkrSmLeAyHDMmAZbssgXJGdWApqMKoqIOKqxQFK14yjqSozj4arPHOFjvK1sSJolcDJcgIzAGZvoRH1zVMWAtZDQC5oNTNf4PkgxADXAiAAGT7RkYgKHA-i7WkqTpKJLWfKJ5AAPx-t4cqxG9cCLbWUhvbE+nltVlZ7iZ627aQSqCM9dAfUtDWzb+GldmO4b9qmcaGieXGpjxmbZu1N55t1kO0FtpYGQDtX7qZ9aNs2hrtrQ9OIJ2QasSjsbIEOqCjqGyNTmjs4qUuq7rpuho7hT-JkH+J4ScBeOdXe+wk9TL5yZ+F4-oz3gTv1guXihkEdbeMEq-BevIeBWSa3+mHYUSauIauJFw+RtCadRtH0YxLG9mzHGY2mKl8RZVlibLS52Q7BF2eHIb+RplEe7pf1VTVVaU+tNoh8JYm2TJDkyU5MkuTJbkyR5MleTJPkyX56lBYFIXGGFRJRQQMV6PFyBjRNaUZWAlJYAAMnA8jKvS4CMpwKeGenwNCiKYoSm1UHyoT8bzRqq+6uk+p-saWCmgBIF1C8P4n4dx2nf4J9Xddt3QKJ58rdMo1yElJ2TdNIHmfzhZ2g6J0xAfr-GmGtBeP9aYFE2sWR8PoyLFQ7IjHmE42Z-28BjKc2MHB8SvPjLq6DDQkxnuTOeNZ1oqygT4RmjNmbdl9nzDmw5ubjknAOHq3hw7LiIiLRBERxZkIPNLACsc8EK3vLApApso5fmtvGHWgF1b60tmcI2soTbPjNvJQiiADZoS1nQW2wJcKxydqRNsfCmaJ20p7BizFWbsVIJxLBQdjDZ2slwyOscY563jqqaxOl6IkLTkDchC8s6CRzjZOyBclJFyUiXJSZclIVyUlXJSNclJ1wCkFIAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for that super extensive answer!